# MYSQL Query in Access

Tags: ms-access

Getting 'wrong number of arguments used with function in Query exp' error

```
SELECT DISTINCT MATERIAL
FROM EORD
GROUP BY Material
HAVING SUM(IIF(CDate(Format([Valid To],"####/##/##")) < now()),0,1) = 0;
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Access? They're totally different products.

Comment: its showing that your function contain different no of argument while you are passing different no of arguments

Comment: 'if' spelling mistake..can you share your function code

Comment: Removed the mysql tag because this isn't MySQL valid code... next time tag the correct database.

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal iif is legit in Access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parentheses are wrong. `IIF()` takes 3 arguments, you only gave it 1. `SUM()` takes 1 argument, you gave it 3. It should be:

```
HAVING SUM(IIF(CDate(Format([Valid To],"####/##/##")) < now(),0,1)) = 0;
```